# divide a file according ranges in other file with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a file in linux:

The file has ranges of numbers, the file is like:

```
100,500
501,1000
1001,2000
```

And i have other file with a word and the numbers:

```
a,105
b,110
c,550
d,670
e,900
f,80
h,1500
```

Then i need filter the file and generate files according the ranges in the first file.
Then i need 3 files:

```
<<110,500>>
a,105
b,110

<<501,1000>>
c,550
d,670
e,900

<<1001,2000>>
h,1500
```

With a bash script

i can read the first file like:

```
while read line
do
   init=`echo $line | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}{print $1}'`
   end=`echo $line | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}{print $2}'`    
done <rangos.txt
```

And i have the ranges, but i don't know how can i divide the second file according the ranges of the first file.

Who can help me?

Thanks

Comment: I guess that should be `<<100,500>>` instead of `<<110,500>>` ?

Comment: what about f,80 ? I can't see it in your output. Is it a typo or is it removed because it was not sorted ?

Comment: And the second file separator is space ?

Comment: I might use `perl` or another language for this. While it can be done it bash, it might be more readable in something else.

Answer (score 1):

Here a sample parser in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare file1=file1
declare file2=file2
while read line; do 
  if [ -z "${line}" ]; then continue; fi # empty lines 
  declare -i left=${line%%,*}
  declare -i right=${line##*,}

  echo "<<$left,$right>>"

  OIFS=$IFS
  IFS=' '
  for word in $(<$file2); do
    declare letter=${word%%,*}
    declare -i value=${word##*,}

    if [[ $left -le $value && $value -le $right ]]; then
      echo "$letter,$value"
    fi
  done
  IFS=$OIFS
done < "${file1}"
```

Tested under Debian Wheezy with bash4, it print:

```
$ ./parser.sh 
<<100,500>>
a,105
b,110
<<501,1000>>
c,550
d,670
e,900
<<1001,2000>>
h,1500
```

However, in the light of your comment about perl or other language, then you should do it in the language you or your team is more familiar with.

Comment: The language of choice is `bash`. You have simple flat-files on a system that require only simple parsing and use of parameter expansion which is what bash was created to do. While perl can also do it, loading the perl interpreter is orders of magnitude slower than using bash as intended.

Comment: I said that because I don't see the real interest, apart from learning, of this read and split. I presume there might be some more work to do, left out of the question. On a side note, I do love bash, but not everyone knows it and it can be hard to maintain. Well, Perl too.

Comment: I knew what you meant and didn't mean to step on your toes. After close to two decades on Linux, I see so many fundamental misunderstandings regarding the correct tool for the job it is almost bewildering. And it really boils down to this. If the native shell is capable of solving the problem, then that is the correct tool for the job. It is only if native shell either (1) can't do the job, or (2) requires a forced hack of a solution, (and I'll add (3) cannot meet the performance requirements of a project), then some other solution is needed. If not, you are far better served by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the two file are not sorted and that the second file have a word and a number per line.

In this case you can do something like this:

```
> out_file.txt
while read line; do
   init=${line#*,}
   end=${line%,*}  
   echo "<<$init,$end>>" >> out_file.txt
   while read wnum; do
       theNum=${wnum#*,}
       if [ $theNum -le $end ] && [ $theNum -ge $init ]; then
         echo "$wnum" >> out_file.txt
       fi
   done < word_and_num.txt
done <rangos.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be a lot easier with `awk`:

```
BEGIN { FS = "," }
NR==FNR {
    map[$0];     # load data in hash
    next
}
{
    ++count;
    file = "file" count ".txt";   # create your filename
    print "<<" $0 ">>" > file;    # add the header to filename
    for (data in map) {
        split (data, fld, /,/);
        if ( $1 <= fld[2] && fld[2] <= $2 ) {  # add entries if in range
            print (data) > file
        }
    }
    close(file)     # close your file
}
```

Save the above script in say `script.awk`. Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk datafile rangefile
```

This will create three files:

```
$ head file*

==> file1.txt <==
<<100,500>>
a,105
b,110

==> file2.txt <==
<<501,1000>>
c,550
d,670
e,900

==> file3.txt <==
<<1001,2000>>
h,1500
```